# creating a text menu, user can't enter option again

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import re
import time

print('MAIN MENU')
print('1. Plot Graph A')
print('2. Plot Graph B')
print('3. Plot Graph C')
print('4. History')
print('5. Exit/Quit')

choice=raw_input('Please choose an option')
if choice == '1':
   import plotA
elif choice == '2':
   import plotB
elif choice == '3':
   import plotC
elif choice == '4':
   import history
elif choice == '5':
   exit()
elif choice!='':
   print('Try Again')
```

so when i run the module, i can enter my choice eg. i enter '4' when it is done, you should be able to type your choices again but it can't

i know you can't just import it, but i dont know other way of doing it

thanks in advance:)

Comment: If you want to iterate through the choices again why cant you use a while loop?

Comment: Wrap the code in a `while` loop and introduce another option choosing which the user can signal that he is finished.

Comment: I don't know if you realize this, but if you `import history` twice, the second time, nothing at all will happen. You generally don't want to import a module just to run its top-level code; move the actual code in each module into a function, then import the modules (which now just define functions) at the top of your code, then do `history.history()` instead of `import history` inside the menu.

Comment: hi abarnert thanks for advise, do you have any examples to illustrate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe do you want this?

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import re
import time


def get_choice():
    print('MAIN MENU')
    print('1. Plot Graph A')
    print('2. Plot Graph B')
    print('3. Plot Graph C')
    print('4. History')
    print('5. Exit/Quit')

    choice = raw_input('Please choose an option: ')
    if choice == '1':
        import plotA
    elif choice == '2':
        import plotB
    elif choice == '3':
        import plotC
    elif choice == '4':
        import history
    elif choice == '5':
        exit()
    else:
        print('Try Again')
        get_choice()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_choice()
```

You can call from anywhere. example:

```
elif choice == '4':
    import history
    get_choice()
```

If you don't want to use recursive function;

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import re
import time


def get_choice():
    print('MAIN MENU')
    print('1. Plot Graph A')
    print('2. Plot Graph B')
    print('3. Plot Graph C')
    print('4. History')
    print('5. Exit/Quit')

    choice = raw_input('Please choose an option: ')
    if choice == '1':
        import plotA
    elif choice == '2':
        import plotB
    elif choice == '3':
        import plotC
    elif choice == '4':
        import history
    elif choice == '5':
        exit()
    else:
        print('Try Again')
        return False
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        if get_choice() is True:
            break
```

Comment: what is the get_choice() at the below for?

Comment: does it act like a if__name__=='__main__'

Comment: Using recursion instead of a loop is a bad idea in Python. Besides not being Pythonic and confusing novices, because Python doesn't do tail call elimination, you just pile up stack frames until eventually you get a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Be careful, you are using recursion here. I advice a loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate through the choices again you can use a while loop:

```
while True:
    choice=raw_input('Please choose an option')
    if choice == '1':
       import plotA
    elif choice == '2':
       import plotB
    elif choice == '3':
       import plotC
    elif choice == '4':
       import history
    elif choice == '5':
       exit() # or just break
    elif choice!='':
       print('Try Again')
```

Answer (score 1):

The response of [Ashoka Lella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3148952/ashoka-lella) is fine, but don't forget the `break`.

```
while True:
    choice=raw_input('Please choose an option')
    if choice == '1':
       import plotA
       break
    elif choice == '2':
       import plotB
       break
    elif choice == '3':
       import plotC
       break
    elif choice == '4':
       import history
       break
    elif choice == '5':
       exit() # or just break
    elif choice!='':
       print('Try Again')
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use ```elif``` as opposed to just ```if```? As long as you have the break statements, would you get the same result?

Comment: You are right. Here, `if` would do the same as `elif`. Anyway, `elif` does not use more memory than if.